# Run cron every nth second of every minute?

Tags: cron

What would be the cron expression for "nth second of every minute"?

For example, for every 5th second of every minute, the cron would run at 1:00:05, 1:01:05, 1:02:05 and so on..  24x7.

I could not find any documentation for achieving this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not available out of the box. What you could do is prepend your command with `sleep`, so it would be:

`sleep 5 && /app/script.sh`

Answer (score -3):

Figured it out. The cron expression would be.

```
5 * 0 ? * *
```